# typeError _ref is undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs

I jump into react with just the basic about javascript, I'm making a query in my server that handle mysql and the connection is fine but the return is where I have a problem,it suppose to return a JSON with the query but I found error typeError _ref is undefined here is the function where I connect to my API

```
callDB(){
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/lista')
    .then((response)=>{
        response.json()
    })
    .then(({data})=>{
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((err)=>{console.log(err);});
}
```

In the data part is where it doesn't work any ideas?thanks before anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return `response.json()` in your Promise handler :

```
callDB(){
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/lista')
    .then((response)=>{
        return response.json()
    })
    .then(({data})=>{
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((err)=>{console.log(err);});
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It happens when trying to destructure an object from the `undefined` value, in your case it's `{ data }`.

So in this particular case returning response.json() from the previous then() handler helps, but other readers may have this problem in other cases as well, in this case you either need to provide a default value like `{}` or explicitly check for `undefined` before trying to desctucture